# Is there any idea to get jwt token in django?

Tags: python, django

i'm doing my own project.
communicate python program - django server.
first is when program send information about signup(like name, password, id etc.) server return success signal.
next step is when program send login information about sign(like name, password), server return jwt token and program receive jwt token.
I'm try everything what i know... but i don't know how to return jwt token to python program.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a proper way to generate the token correctly:

- create an endpoint to login with credentials (note the csrf_exempt to allow POST calls from your program)

```
path('/login', csrf_exempt(login)) )
```

- create a view to process the request - to protect the credentials, expect them as the payload of a POST request:

```
@require_POST
def login(request):
  username = request.data.get('username', None)
  password = request.data.get('password', None)
  if username is None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest('username is missing')
  if password is None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest('password is missing')

  # validate the user/credentials
  your_function_to_validate(username, password)

  jwt =  your_function_to_generate_and_save_the_JWT(username, password)
  return HttpResponse(jwt)
```

- call the endpoint using the Python program:

```
url = base_url + '/login'

credentials = {
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': '12345'
}
res = post(url, data=credentials)

if res.status_code != 200:
    # deal with bad credentials
    pass

jwt = res.data
```